# How do I estimate my tax refund if I've held multiple jobs?

Tags: united-states, income-tax

I earn about 65000 a year, from a few different jobs that I've held this year.

What is an approach that I can take to estimate what I'm going to get back as a refund this year?

More details:

- I've paid $9,750 in Federal taxes so far this year.
- I've paid $2,000 in student loan interest
- I believe that I have donated about $1,000 to charity.

Comment: To get something back you need to first give something. Have you had your taxes withheld? At what level? And, of course - what country and/or state are you paying taxes at?

Comment: Don't just vote the guy down. Edit the question.

Comment: This is going to depend very much on your location, so I've tagged this as 'united-states', based on a reasonable guess.

Comment: Note that it shouldn't depend on how many jobs you've held, just on your income, taxes deducted, etc. Note also that your charity donations are worthless unless you have receipts from them.

Comment: @ChrisInEdmonton That depends on the nature of your job(s). If you work part-time, sometimes employers withhold taxes assuming that they are your only employer. Also, folks with second jobs with variable compensation (waiters, salesmen) occasionally get "surprised" at tax time.

Comment: If that $1000 is the only potential deduction, he will take the standard deduction nstead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most reliable way is to take a 1040 and pretend its January 2012. It's pretty close so you should be able to guess at the last few paychecks of 2011.

As a bonus, you're also prepared to file quickly when the official documents arrive.

Answer (score 1):

It's a hard question to answer in this forum, but there are tax calculators out there that will help you get a rough idea of what you owe or are due back as a refund.

Here's one:

http://www.1040.com/site/tax-tools/tax-estimator/